# Bootstrap resposive wont work on mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I used Bootstrap for groundwork to develop the site to be responsive. The problem i have encountered is that when I try to watch to watch a site on mobile or tablet device the site wont response to the screen resolution. But when I try the Responsive Design View on Mozilla it all works fine. They order of included css files is Bootstrap, then my custom css and some custom query css which I used to tweak some content things.

Comment: Hard to say without any code...

Comment: did you specified the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following within your head of your page?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

If the above does not work can you please paste some code from your page for us to see what the issue could be? Thanks.